# consumer.setConsumeFromWhere(ConsumeFromWhere.CONSUME_FROM_FIRST_OFFSET) no use

Tags: rocketmq

I want to read data from last offset, but use:

```
consumer.setConsumeFromWhere(ConsumeFromWhere.CONSUME_FROM_LAST_OFFSET)
```

No effect.

Answer (score 1):

`ConsumeFromWhere.CONSUME_FROM_LAST_OFFSET` only works when your consumer connect to broker in the first time.

You may want to use `sh mqadmin resetOffsetByTime` to reset the offset to now. More details please refer to [here](http://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/cli-admin-tool/).